# Why I always get 0 when getting retweets of a tweet using status ID? Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to get retweets of a tweet and I know the tweet ID, but I always get 0 (the size of list statuses is always 0). I've checked the tweet I am searching for has retweets, but the return is 0. Could someone tell why? Thanks a lot. Here is my code:

```
public class getRetweets {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
              .setOAuthConsumerKey("key")
              .setOAuthConsumerSecret("keysecret")
              .setOAuthAccessToken("token")
              .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("tokensecret");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(Long.parseLong("523516722331271169"));
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get retweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not familiar with your library, but why are you using `Long.parseLong(....` - you should be able to just pass it the string "523516722331271169".

Comment: Thank you very much! This problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following and verify if you even have any retweets for the given tweetID.

```
        Status statusTemp = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong("523516722331271169"));
        System.out.println(statusTemp.getText());
        System.out.println(statusTemp.getRetweetCount());
```

Are you sure you are looking up correct tweetID?

Answer (score 0):

The tweet with the ID you provided seems to have 0 retweets. Your code seems to be fine. I just checked it with tweets that definitely have retweets.

```
public void test(){
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(conf);
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    Query query = new Query("from:BBCBreaking Lynda Bellingham");
    query.setLang("en");
    QueryResult result = null;
    try {
        result = twitter.search(query);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for(Status status : result.getTweets()){
        if(status.getRetweetCount() > 0){

            long id = status.getId();

            List<Status> statuses = null;
            try {
                statuses = twitter.getRetweets(id);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Start Retweet Section------------------");
            for (Status retweet : statuses) {
                System.out.println("@" + retweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }
            System.out.println("End Retweet Section------------------");

        }
    }
}
```

The output looks as follow:

Start Retweet Section------------------

@PattenAdam - Lynda Bellingham, who has died after battling cancer...

@brunoappr - Lynda Bellingham, who has died after battling cancer...

@poguesfan4ever - Lynda Bellingham, who has died after battling cancer...

End Retweet Section------------------

Start Retweet Section------------------

@holdbxcktherain - British actress and presenter Lynda Bellingham, who had cancer...

@Dusty_Milo - British actress and presenter Lynda Bellingham, who had cancer...

@_aaaamy - British actress and presenter Lynda Bellingham, who had cancer...

End Retweet Section------------------